# How to set common header for http

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am setting comon header for all $htpp calls using angular js

```
angular.module('sample module').run(function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['token']='ticket' ;
});
```

But i need to set for all html files also common header for security reasons ,that will be validating the service .

Is that possible ,please suggest

Comment: Try with $decorator the $http service

Answer (score 0):

Try set common header for all requests like this

```
angular.module('sample module').config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['token']='ticket';}]);
```

Hope it help to you.